# WiFi hotspot not working on Fedora 20

Tags: wireless-networking, fedora, wireless-access-point

I used to be able to create wifi hotspots on Fedora 20 on the settings -> network screen and clicking on the "use as access point" button:

[image] [image]

A couple months ago it stopped working. If I recall correctly, it was after I installed either `dnsmasq` or `dnsmasq-utils`, but I might be wrong. The fact is when I click the button and the 2nd screen shows up, an error message is displayed saying something like "Connection activation failed" (see below). **The system acts as if the hotspot is up, but no device can see the SSID.**

[image]

I followed [these steps](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/40383/how-to-create-and-configure-a-hotspot-in-fedora-20/) and used `nm-connection-editor` to create a new entry on `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

and then performing

```
# change the settings how you like
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
#restart NetworkManager
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
# bring up the AP
nmcli con up Hotspot ifname <name>
```

but I just get a CLI error message "Error: Connection activation failed" and the same visual error indicator from before.

`journalctl -r` registers this:

> gnome-session[1722]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?

Content of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot`:

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=<string>
type=wifi
autoconnect=false

[wifi]
ssid=<MACHINE.DOMAIN>
mode=ap
mac-address=<MAC>
security=802-11-wireless-security

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=none
wep-key0=b193294394
wep-key-type=1

[ipv4]
method=shared

[ipv6]
method=auto
```

Comment: Please post your `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot`.